# How to read file .csv per batch

Tags: php, csv, php-5.3

I have a question so my .csv

```
"product";"date";"q"
"8";"1995-05-01";"4"
"8";"1995-05-01";"2"
"8";"2001-05-01";"13"
"8";"2001-05-01";"3"
"9";"1995-05-01";"1"
```

I have about 1 milion rows.
I'm doing something like this:

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($fpointer, 4096, ";")) !== false) {
     $data[$row[0]][$row[2]][] = $row;
}
```

But this process consume a lot of memory. How I can do in other way? Please help me.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: A lot of inserts in datatabse

Comment: The problem is that your `$data` array will contain all of the file (hence the memory problem).  If possible, you need to write this data as soon as you can to the database (if that's what your reading it for).

Comment: How much memory is it using? Is that memory usage a problem?

Comment: If you can add the code which adds `$data` to the database, this may help in solving your problem.

Comment: Assuming the database you use allows batch inserts, you can perform an insert of maybe 1000 rows at a time. Then unset your array and start over. This will keep your memory usage to a fixed amount. Alternatively, do a bulk insert in your database using the CSV directly. E.g. MySQL's LOAD DATA or SQL Server's BULK INSERT.

Comment: If I calculate it correctly your CSV file is about 250 MB and should not be an issue to hold in memory

Comment: Server killed the process of read and insert this data. I need somehow to group and make the treatment by batch

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using more than the limit of memory, do not read all the memory and then process when processing very large data sets. You can process your data in batches in a loop, for example:

```
$limit = 0;
$data = [];

while($row = fgetcsv($fpointer, 4096, ";")) {
    $limit++;
    $data[$row[0]][$row[2]][] = $row;

    if (1000 <= $limit) {
        // process your data
        $data = [];
        $limit = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SplFileObject::fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.fgetcsv.php)

`SplFileObject` allow you to read line by line, specified size (`SplFileObject::fread`) and etc without loading whole file into memory.

I tested up to `3.5GB` file size without any issues.

Reference: https://github.com/sridharkalaibala/PHPLogFileViewer